# Google Sheets error - Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch

Tags: function, google-sheets, service, urlfetch

I have problem with my function in Google Sheets. I am getting every day this error: "Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch." I have about 1000 urls in document. I am looked for solution at google. I find some topics where is recommended to add cache to function but I dont know how to do it. Does somebody have any idea? My function:

```js
    function ImportCeny(url, HTMLClass) { 
      var output = ''; 
      var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}); 
      if (fetchedUrl) { 
        var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText(); 
      } 
      // Grace period to avoid call limit 
      Utilities.sleep(1000); 
      var priceposition = html.search(HTMLClass);
      return html.slice(priceposition,priceposition + 70).match(/(-\d+|\d+)(,\d+)*(\.\d+)*/g); 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices?hl=en#use_the_cache_service) shows clearly how to use the Cache service. For another example, see [GoogleMapsCached](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/138411570?msgid=139009654).

Comment: [This link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices?hl=en#use_the_cache_service) about caching may help...

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add a randomly generated number, for example 6 digits and add this number to the URL as a parameter each time before calling "*UrlFetchApp*"

i.e.;

url = url & "?t=458796"

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use `Utilities.sleep()` to force the program to stop for some time before making the next call. However, using the built-in Cache class (you can see the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache)) is much more suitable as it is specially designed for these scenarios.
So, if you wanted to leave one second you could replace:

```js
Utilities.sleep(1000); //In milliseconds
```

with

```js
var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache(); //Create a cache instance
cache.put("my_content", html, 1); // In seconds
```